# fastify and prisma with postgres session storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, prisma, fastify

I am building a nodejs api that uses fastify, Prisma and Postgres. I have the API working with fastify-cookies and fastify-session and i can get cookies just fine but i need to be able to store the session cookies in the database. I saw a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COFY7QiDswA&ab_channel=JayWolfe) on doing this but it was without prisma, so im lost on how to connect fastify-session to the Prisma database pool.

I user the prisma client to connect to the database to do my normal calls in my routes, `const data = await prisma.model.create({});`

server.js

```
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true });
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Session state
fastify.register(require('./sessions'));

// Register all our routes here.
...

// Startup code for the fastify server.
const start = async () => {
  try {
    await fastify.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0');
  } catch (error) {
    fastify.log.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

// Start the fastify server.
start();
```

sessions.js

```
const cookie = require('fastify-cookie');
const session = require('fastify-session');
const fp = require('fastify-plugin');

/**
 * @param {import('fastify').FastifyInstance} fastify
 */
const plugin = async (fastify) => {
  // All plugin data here is global to fastify.
  fastify.register(cookie);
  fastify.register(session, {
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    store: new SessionStore({
      tableName: 'UserSession',
      pool: ???,   <--------------------------------- how to connect?
    }),
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false,
    },
  });

  fastify.addHook('preHandler', (req, reply, next) => {
    req.session.user = {};
    next();
  });
};

module.exports = fp(plugin);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Prisma connection pool you would have to create a session storage library similar to `connect-pg-simple` or modify the codebase to accept a Prisma connection. This is definitely a non-trivial implementation and I don't think it would make a lot of sense without exceptional circumstances.

I would suggest creating a new `pg.Pool` or `pgPromise` instance and connecting with that like it was shown in the [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COFY7QiDswA) you linked to. There's no reason you can't have two separate connection pools open to the same database (One with Prisma and one with pg.Pool)